# Retrieve only rows with specific data(number) from mysql database "XCODE"

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, localhost

Im facing an issue with retrieving data from mysql database.

In my database, I have several columns which stand for different values. The problematic column is the one with ID (userNumber), where in many cases are these numbers different. For example, I want to download the whole rows where userNumber = 5. To this point, is everything working fine, because in my php file Ive got something like this :

```
$UserNumber = "5";
            $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE UserNumber = '$UserNumber'";
```

But here comes the issue. I want the users to insert this number into textfield (in app) and then this number is sent to php file where it downloads only rows where UserNumber = 5("TextFieldName").

I know, its silly question, but I am facing this issue for several weeks and I couldn't find my answer on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're passing the string '$UserNumber' to sql instead of passing the value of the variable. You could use string concatenation which will fix the problem but open the potential for SQL injection. Look to use parameterized SQL commands

Comment: Like Greg said, you _really_ should look into prepared statements.

Comment: where is your php file located ?